# configuring spring mvc tiles and view resolver in java

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to configure internal view resolver alongwith tiles in spring. But, to my various attempts and answers searched, its still not working. If I remove the internal view resolver configuration and then tiles is working fine. But, if I configure tiles and internal view resolver together and configure tiles file accordingly then, things are not working at all. Any solution for this ? Tried to set the order also, but it didn't work at all. 
Below is the configuration file in java.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.springmvc")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer(){
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml"});
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        TilesViewResolver viewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

Tiles.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"  "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">  

<tiles-definitions>  

   <!-- Base Definition -->
   <definition name="base-definition" 
       template="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/layouts/defaultLayout.jsp">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
       <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/template/defaultHeader.jsp" />  
       <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/template/defaultMenu.jsp" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="" />  
       <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/template/defaultFooter.jsp" />  
   </definition>  

   <!-- Home Page -->
   <definition name="home" extends="base-definition">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/pages/home.jsp" />  
   </definition>  

   <!-- Product Page -->
   <definition name="products" extends="base-definition">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Products" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/pages/products.jsp" />  
   </definition>  

   <!-- Contact-us Page -->
   <definition name="contactus" extends="base-definition">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Us" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/pages/contactus.jsp" />  
   </definition>  

</tiles-definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the order for the Tiles View Resolver Bean in your App Config

```
viewResolver.setOrder(0);
```

It should work and please note that Set the order of the Internal View Resolver as highest("Lowest priority").

Comment: I am using xml config file and it is working perfectly buddy!!1